# Windows 8 Install SSD Issues

Tags: windows-8, installation, ssd

I'm having an annoying problem regarding installing Windows 8 on my SSD. I have a 40gb ssd (Corsair F40) which I'm trying to install Windows 8 on by using a flash drive. When running setup, the ssd is listed when installation asks me where I want to install Windows. However, should I refresh the page, the drive and it's two partitions vanish.

I didn't have this issue installing Windows 7. My motherboard is a Gigabyte 797X-Gaming 7. Any ideas about what this is and how to fix it would be great

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed this by changing the SATA port that my hard drive was plugged into. There seem to be three groups of sata ports each ran by a different chip so I'm not sure if only one of those groups work without extra drivers or something like that. Any further explanation from someone more technically minded wouldn't go amiss.